# How to set up and evaluate line integral for non trivial ellipse?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

My task is as follows:

$$\: \mathcal{C}:\textbf{r}(t) = \big(1 + 2\cos(t)\big)\:\hat{i} + \big(3\sin(t) - 2\big)\: \hat{j},\enspace t\in [0, 2\pi].$$

Calculate $\oint_\mathcal{C} \textbf{F}\:d\textbf{r}$ when: 
$$\textbf{F}(x,y) = y^2\:\hat{i} + x\: \hat{j}.$$

My work goes as follows;

The definition is: $$\oint_\mathcal{C} \textbf{F}\:d\textbf{r} = \int_a^b \textbf{F}\left(\textbf{r}(t)\right)\textbf{r}'(t)\:dt = \iint_R \left( Q_x - P_y\right)\:dxdy.$$

Where $Q_x, P_y$ are partial derivatives.

With this at hand we have: 
$$\textbf{r}'(t) = -2\sin(t)\: \hat{i} \:+ 3\cos(t)\:\hat{j},\enspace \textbf{F}\left(\textbf{r}(t)\right) = \left(3\sin(t) - 2\right)^2\:\hat{i} + \left(1 + 2\cos(t) \right)\:\hat{j}.$$

And: $$\textbf{F}\left(\textbf{r}(t)\right)\textbf{r}'(t) = 3\cos(t) + 6\cos^2(t) - 18\sin^3(t) + 24\sin^2(t) - 8\sin(t).$$

While i think i've calculated this right, i get the feeling that this could be done in a much easier way. I would like to try the last step of the definition, but im, not sure how to set up those boundaries with a non-trivial ellipse like this i.e. where center $S(1,-2)$ and radiuses $a = 2, b = 3.$

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is more manageable doing the integral over the ellipse.

You can use some changes of variables to integrate over the ellipse $(\frac{x-1}{2})^2+(\frac{y+2}{3})^2\le 1$. First take $u=\frac{x-1}{2}$ $v=\frac{y+2}{3}$.

Then you have:

$\int\int_R (Q_x-P_y)dxdy=\int\int_R (1-2y)dxdy=\int\int_D (5-6v)6dudv$

where $D$ is the unit disc.

Then use polar coordinates $u=r\cos\theta, v=r\sin\theta$ so you get:

$6\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi} (5-6r\sin\theta)rd\theta dr=30\pi$

Comment: Thanks alot, that clarified things and refreshed the good  old substitution technique i should have used!